# SSIS "The binary code for the script is not found" on script task

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ssis, script-task

I'm seeing that a lot of people are having this issue and so am I.
I'm using Visual studio 2015 SSDT 2014 and SQL server 2014. 
I created a package that has a script task in it, inside the script task I'm using a web reference to a SOAP API.

when i run the package from my design environment (Visual studio) that package successfully executes. when I deploy the package to the integration services catalog I get the following error:
 `"The binary code for the script is not found. Please open the script in the designer by clicking Edit Script button and make sure it builds successfully."`

I know that from SSDT 2012 and higher the "precompiled binary" option is set to true.

what am i missing?

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

have try tried to add service reference, instead of web reference ?

- keep backup of proxy class that generated by web reference
- delete the web reference
- add same service as service reference
- replace newly generated proxy class with the backup in step 1

Comment: i did except the ones with the proxy class. i dont know what that is

Comment: can you skip the proxy class thing and try with service reference.